# What's going on with Rails ActiveRecord Dynamic Classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, metaprogramming

If I have a User model in Rails 4 and call `User.all.inspect` I get something like

`"#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 2, first_name: ...`

reporting the class as an active record relation. However calling `User.all.class` yields `User::ActiveRecord_Relation` which appears to be a dynamically created class for active records of Users. I've tested that I can metaprogram methods on `User::ActiveRecord_Relation` and they work as expected.

I've tried digging around in the rails source but couldn't find where these classes were being created. Can somebody explain what's going on an point me to where this is happening in the rails source if possible? Thanks!

Comment: So I used `User.all.class.ancestors` to find out what this class consists of. Turns out it includes `ActiveRecord::Delegation::ClassSpecificRelation`. So I dug up `.../activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb` (using RubyMine). There on line 20 you will find the culprit.

Comment: And a bit further down on line 35 of that same file you will find an explanation of why these dynamic subclasses exist.

Comment: And even a bit further down on line 60 of that same file you will find the reason why the class self-identifies as its superclass upon inspection. (That is with `#inspect`. Note that upon calling `#to_s` the relation identifies as an instance of `User::ActiveRecord_Relation`.)

Comment: And see `.../activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation.rb:633` for the implementation of `#inspect`.

Comment: Credit to @Raffael but rather than digging through your gems folder here is the [GitHub Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L51)

Comment: Thanks @Raffael ! found the answers I was looking for =)